# Get environment name

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm writing a GitHub Actions workflow that is meant to deploy some Terraform code to our staging/production environment:

```
name: Deploy On Release

on:
    workflow_dispatch:

permissions:
    contents: read
    actions: read
    pull-requests: write
    security-events: write

jobs:
    deploy-tf-stage:
        if: github.event.prerelease
        uses: ./.github/workflows/deployment.yml
        environment: stage
        with:
            environment: "stage"

    deploy-tf-prod:
        if: !github.event.prerelease
        uses: ./.github/workflows/deployment.yml
        environment: prod
        with:
            environment: "prod"
```

As you can see here, the `environment` input to the GitHub workflow is the same as the environment name.

I've already looked through the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment#using-an-environment) and I see I could add them as variables to be imported, but this seems like a bit of a brittle solution, considering that we've set the environment name to the value we're using for this variable, intentionally.

Is there any way I can get the name of the environment here so I don't have two values floating around?

Comment: If the `github.event.prerelease` is a boolean, it shouldn't be necessary to inform the quotes `'` right? Otherwise the value will be treated as string.

Comment: @GuiFalourd the quotes are already implicit _in the YAML_. The fact that GHA will replace the value with the calculated (boolean) result of the expression it contains later on _in the object_ doesn't matter (although if you did `${{ '!github.event.prerelease' }}`, i.e. the quotes were actually _in_ the expression, that would change the behaviour).

Comment: @GuiFalourd Sorry, this is yet another happy side affect of copy-paste. I have removed the quotes.

Comment: You can see what's exposed to the job here: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts. The vars and secrets defined in the environment are, its name isn't. However you could reduce duplication by setting the actual environment _inside_ the reusable workflow based on the input (e.g. [here](https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit/blob/1e4a2f9cc4df2ba2594ad22b566d611af26a47a8/.github/workflows/push.yml#L63-L64) -> [here](https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit/blob/1e4a2f9cc4df2ba2594ad22b566d611af26a47a8/.github/workflows/deploy.yml#L18-L20)).

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for the confirmation. I read that document and it referenced `${{ vars.ENVIRONMENT_STAGE }}` but I wasn't sure if that was a builtin or an example of how you'd use it.